# Do my flowers have a higher spawn rate if my friend waters them?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I recently stumbled upon this Google sheet sent to me by a friend: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nI2JcIls4JnDZthCV88xx_X800h3wopKuV8yzqyVO1E/htmlview#gid=0

The claim is simple. Plants watered by your online friend seem to have more than a double spawn rate than ones you watered yourself.

I figured if this was accurate I'd be able to find talk online about this, bit couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know whether this true or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier today I saw [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnimalCrossing/comments/g5b8s3/ive_asked_few_visitors_to_water_my_flowers/) reddit post claiming it to be true. 
The person who postet it even put another similar google document in the comments.